# Reference an optidef problem with subequation labels

Tags: cross-referencing, optidef

How do I cross-reference (preferably with `cleveref`) a whole optidef problem that has labels on subequations?

For example, consider the last example in the doc:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/optidef/optidef.pdf

I can reference each subequation, e.g. `(28a)`. But how do I reference the whole problem: `(28)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the code of the `mini!` optimization problem given on the final page of the package's user guide:

```
\begin{mini!}|s|[2]<b>
{w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)\label{eq:ObjectiveExample3}}
{\label{eq:Example3}}
{w^*=}
\addConstraint{g(w)}{=0 \label{eq:C1Example3}}
\addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6 \label{eq:C2Example3}}
\addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p \label{eq:C3Example3}}
\addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.\label{eq:C4Example3}}
\end{mini!}
```

The `mini!` environment takes 3 *optional* arguments -- here: `s`, `2`, and `b` -- and 4 *required* arguments, the third of which is given as follows: `\label{eq:Example3}`.

In section 3.1, "Definition of problem parameters" (pp. 5f.), of the package's user guide, one finds the following characterization of the third required argument (under item #vii): "it defines the main and general reference for the optimization problem. It is used for the `mini` and `mini!` enviro[n]ments."

Hence, do give `eq.~\eqref{eq:Example3}` or -- since you would like to use the `cleveref` package -- `\cref{eq:Example3}` a try.

Comment: I totally missed that; thanks.